# PHP show same variable with different values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP script that generates a random between 0 and 10. AJAX that on click runs the PHP script again.

What I want: Display $var and remember its value (show it on the page), then run the AJAX and show the second value of the $var (show it on the page along with the first value).

I'm very bad using AJAX so excuse my messy code.

PHP File

```
<?php
    $var = rand(0,10);
    echo $var;
?>
```

HTML FILE

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
<button id="button" type="button">Click Me</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'attack3.php',
            success: function(data) {
                $("div").html(data);
            }
        });
 });
});

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
var ok = true;

 if (ok === true) {
      var div = document.createElement('div');

      div.className = 'new-rect';       
        //div.style.backgroundColor = "black";

   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
}
};
</script>
<div id="text"></div>
```

The output will be :

4
4

On button click:

7
7
7

I want as an example the output to be:

7
1
5

(random numbers between 0,10)

Is there any way I could achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't want the same number to be generated again?

Comment: Each time you click button you create `div` and put recieved value in all your `div`s on page

Comment: I don't want the same number to be generate again. @SatishSaini

Comment: I can see that. Any advice to generate another number on the second div? @DanMiller

Comment: You can use jQuery's `.last()` https://api.jquery.com/last/ to get the last div and add the new number. You might want to give the div's a class so they don't interfere with other divs.

Comment: @helloworld99979 can you check in `network tab of browser` if ajax is returning the random numbers?

Comment: It is @AgamBanga, he is just overwriting all divs with the number instead of assign a new number to a new div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the random API Response, then you can use the simple method to show the numbers like below. You don't need to create a seperate div for it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
<button id="button" type="button">Click Me</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var array = [];
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'attack3.php',
            success: function(data) {
                array.push(data)
                $("div").html(array.join(' '));
            }
        });
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. Now its time to decipher it ^^.